# how to map custom domain to azure cdn endpoint

Tags: azure, dns-hosting, azure-networking, azure-storage, namecheap

I am trying to map my custom domain to my Azure CDN endpoint as instructed [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain?tabs=dns-provider%2Cazure-portal%2Cazure-portal-cleanup#map-the-permanent-custom-domain).  The end goal being to host a static site with custom domain in blob storage. The original instructions are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-host) but the steps are very fragmented.  I am trying to setup the CNAME but it doesn't seem to be working.  Its also frustrating to have to try something, then wait for DNS to propogate to see if I did it right or not.

So right now I have the storage and the CDN endpoint and now I'm at the step where I'm adding a custom domain and it gives me this error.  In namecheap, I created a cname and set the host to my custom domain and value to the azureedge.net URL.

Can someone help me fix what I'm doing wrong or help me verify that I did it right so I can just wait for DNS to propogate?  Thanks!

[image: Azure Error]

[image: namecheap input]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you are doing is correct and you just need to wait for DNS propagation.

You can use `dig yourdomain.com @8.8.8.8` to verify that your DNS settings are correct.

Other than that just wait :)

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I got it to work by changing the host to www in namecheap and also on the CDN making the endpoint www.<mysite>.com.  I think when it was right it finally propogated in 15 minutes or so.  For some reason, namecheap wouldn't take a wildcard for the host name.  I'll keep trying on that but getting the www subdomain working is sufficient for now.